# double string operation at once

Tags: bash

I'd like to extract then substitute on a string. Is there a way to do this in the same command?

Assume I have this variable:

```
var="y=2,4"
```

I want this :

```
2.4
```

with a thing like `${${var#*=}/,/.}`

Comment: Are you expecting the variables `var` and `y` both to have the value `2,4`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In BASH you cannot do multiple string operations in one go like this.

This is technically *not* a single operation but in BASH you can do:

```
var="y=2,4"
[[ "$var" =~ ^.*=(.+)$ ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]/,/.}
2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try `sed`

```
$ var="y=2,4"
$ sed 's/^.*=//;s/,/./g' <<< "$var"
2.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "$var" | sed -n 's/y=//p' | tr , .
```

Comment: [Always quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: No, you actually need double quotes.